# Kotlin CLOB to String

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a function in Oracle that returns a CLOB.
In Java I can use the following code to execute this function and fetch the result:

Oracle function definition in my Repository class:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT GETIDSSTATUS() FROM DUAL")
 Clob getIdsStatus();
```

Conversion to String:

```
Clob idsStatus = dbMonRepository.getIdsStatus();
String idsStatusStr = idsStatus.getSubString(1, Math.toIntExact(idsStatus.length()));
```

What's the equivalent code in Kotlin or any other way to convert the Clob to String?

Comment: just use `val` instead of the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely legal use @Query annotation in your kotlin code. For exmaple like this:

```
@Query("select getidstatus() from dual")
fun getIdStatus(): Clob
```

And then you can write smomething like this:

```
val idsStatus = dbMonRepository.getIdStatus()
val idsStatusStr = idsStatus.getSubstring(1, Math.toIntExact(idsStatus.length)
```